# Large WebGL application loading time

Tags: javascript, networking, webgl, loading

See if somebody were to create a large application based on WebGL. Let's say that it's a 3D micro management game which by itself take approximately 700 Megabytes in files to run it.

How would one deal with the loading of the assets. I would have assumed that it would have to be done asynchronously but I am unsure how exactly it would work.

P.S. I am thinking RollerCoaster Tycoon as an example, but really it's about loading large assets from server to browser.

Comment: well, you want to ship assets just-in-time for starters. that includes loading the next level when almost done with the current. you would also want to cache as much core as possible using webSQL/indexedDB. you might also keep them busy during loading using cutscene animations, tips, or mission details.

Answer (score 2):

Well first off, you dont want your users to download 700 megabytes of data, at least not at once.
One should try to keep as many resources(geometry, textures) as possible procedural.

All data that needs to be downloaded should be loaded in a progressive/on demand manner using multiple [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker.Worker)
since one will probably still need to process the data with javascript which can become quite cpu heavy when having many resources.

Packing the data into larger packages may also be advisable to prevent request overhead.
Sure thing one would gzip all resources and try to preload data as soon as the user hits the website. When using image textures and/or text content, embedding it into the html(using `<img>` and `<script>` tags) allows to exploit the browser cache to some extend.

Using WebSQL/IndexedDB/LocalStorage can be done but due to the currently very low quotas and flaky/not existing implementation of the [quota management api](http://www.w3.org/TR/quota-api/) its not a feasable solution right now.